# Use Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String[] cmdarray, String[] envy, File dir)

Tags: java, python

I want to use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String[] cmdarray, String[] envy, File dir)`,because I use relative direction in my python program. When I write this code; it doesn't work and no error report is shown.

```
  Process proc1=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python /Users/g/Documents/Project/fyp/Q/__init__.py 453454336"，，/Users/g/Documents/Project/fyp/Q/)
proc1.waitFor();
```

**I use java in my mac. python version is 2.7.**

Actually what I want to do in Terminal is:

```
cd /Users/g/Documents/Project/fyp/Q/
python __init__.py
```

Comment: Can you show some Java code that actually compiles?

Answer (score 0):

Seems as if you are passing some arguments to your .py file 
simply use

```
String command = "python /Users/g/Documents/Project/fyp/Q/__init__.py 453454336"
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)
```

Make sure you pass `null` to the environment variables array and third parameter is actually a File object.

Use following code...!

```
File directory = new File("/Users/g/Documents/Project/fyp/Q/"); 
Process proc1=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python /Users/g/Documents/Project/fyp/Q/__init__.py 453454336"，null，directory)
```

Comment: It still doesn't work,and because my .py file need to read other file, I need to  use relative direction.

Comment: As a command line argument ? How your .py file is going to read that file?

Comment: What I try to do is execute my .py program, then .py program will do a lot of work including read file. but the path is : file_dir="./myFile.txt" so I need to change dir.

Comment: I rewrite  my .py file dir use absolute path,then use your answer,It works. But I still don't know how to use Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String[] cmdarray, String[] envy, File dir)